# Python : How to optimize comparison between two large sets?

Tags: python, list, optimization, comparison, nlp

I salute you ! I'm new here, and I've got a little problem trying to optimize this part of code.

I'm reading from two files :

Corpus.txt -----> Contains my text (of 1.000.000 words)

Stop_words.txt -----> Contains my stop_list (of 4000 words)

I must compare each word from my corpus with every word in the stop_list, because I want to have a text without stop words, so I've :
1.000.000*4000 comparisons to do with the code below :

```
fich= open("Corpus.txt", "r")
text = fich.readlines()

fich1= open("stop_words.txt", "r")
stop = fich1.read()

tokens_stop = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(stop)
tokens_stop=sorted(set(tokens_stop))

for line in text :
    tokens_rm = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(line)
    z = [val for val in tokens_rm if val not in tokens_stop]
    for i in z:
        print i
```

My question is : Is there anything to do it differently ? Any structure to optimize it ?

Comment: Why are you doing `sorted(set(tokens_stop))`? Sorting it will return a list which has O(n) linear search compared to set's O(1) membership test. Of course, since it's sorted, you could use bisect module to make the search O(log n), but why not just leave it as a set so you don't need to do up to 4000 comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set of your stop_words, then for every word in your text see if it is in the set.

Actually it looks like you are already using a set. Though I don't know why you are sorting it.

Comment: tokens_rm is a set of 1.000.000 words !

Comment: that's much better (y) i didn't knew that sets remove duplicates ! Thank's

Comment: ahh and I didn't know that sorted() returned an array! I didn't think it would do anything on a set. We both learned something :)